# How to pass the model from a CBV to a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a `view` which I want to use with a custom `form_class`:

```
class CustomCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomCreateForm
    fields = ['field1', 'field2']
```

I want to use this view repeatedly so I can use it with different models, such as:

```
class CreateBook(CustomCreateView)
     model = Books

class CreateCar(CustomCreateView)
     model = Cars
```

Because I want to reuse it, I need a way to pass the `model` from the `CreateView` to the form class. I can't specify it in the form class because then I can't reuse the view between different models.

Is there a way to do this? E.g.

```
class CustomCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        model = kwargs.pop('model')
        self._meta.model = model
        super(CustomCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
       fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a form class factory, pass model to it and create dynamic form class. Override `get_form_class` method in view, and call form factory there like this

```
def form_class_factory(model_class):
    class CustomCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
           model = model_class
           fields = '__all__'
    return CustomCreateForm
```

In view

```
class YourView(CustomCreateView)
     model = Cars

     def get_form_class(self):
         return form_class_factory(self.model)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that approach results in `name 'forms' is not defined`

Comment: Are you importing forms from django on top of file? `from django import forms`

Comment: Got it, thanks. How would I pass an initial value to the form this way? E.g. say I wanted to set a field = to `request.session['myvalue']`?

Comment: You can override `get_initial` method of your view class return a dictionary from there in a way that keys are form fields and values are initial value you want to set for that field. For example, `{'my_field': self.session['myvalue']}` if form field is `my_field`